How to organize large projects in Zig language
I used to break down my large c/c++ projects with CMake and then add each part to main project using add_submodule command (the smaller parts were static or dynamic libraries). Also I used the same solution to use third-party libraries in my project.
But I have trouble with doing the same in my zig projects. I had a hard time to search and try to find a reliable and reusable project structure just like CMake projects.
Is there any solution that make me be able to create smaller libraries (with a build.zig inside each) and use those parts in my projects? for example something like this structure:
|-- projectA
|-----| src
|-----|----| main.zig
|-----| libs
|-----|----| projectB
|-----|----------| src
|-----|---------------| hello.zig
|-----|----------| build.zig
|-----|----| projectC
|-----|----------| src
|-----|---------------| bye.zig
|-----|----------| build.zig
|-----| build.zig

I tried to use build.zig file to build each dependency but was not successful, also it's not a straightforward solution, I searched to find a solution but I found nothing.
I found something like exe.addModule but there is not such a function called addModule() in added executable structure.

Any reason why you want multiple build.zig files instead of just sticking them all into one larger build.zig?

Well imagine projectB and projectC are indipended git repos and are submodules in a larger project. @Cubic

if project B and C are truly independent of A, then why should they be nested in A ?

It's more like a personal preference for some developers, keeping dependencies inside project (via submodules). Consistency and control, modularity and reusability, simplified dependency management. However I'm not so familiar with Zig project structures, so this approach may not be the case for this language. @FObersteiner

that comment maybe was a bit pedantic ;-) I think what you're suggestion is actually quiet helpful if you need to vendor an application.

You can add a dependency as a local package.
Let's say you have this folder structure:
|-- foo
|-----| src
|-----|----| root.zig
|-----| build.zig
|-- project
|-----| src
|-----|----| main.zig
|-----| build.zig
|-----| build.zig.zon

In foo, in build.zig:
_ = b.addModule("foo", .{
    .root_source_file = b.path("src/root.zig"),
    .target = target,
    .optimize = optimize,
});

In the project, in build.zig.zon:
.dependencies = .{
    .foo = .{
        .path = "../foo/",
    },
},

And, in build.zig:
const foo = b.dependency("foo", .{
    .target = target,
    .optimize = optimize,
});
exe.root_module.addImport("foo", foo.module("foo"));

So, in main.zig you can just do:
const foo = @import("foo");

I believe this code works in 0.12 and 0.13.
